# I got an error when I try to run Sidekiq on RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, sidekiq, rubymine

Hi everyone I got an error while I'm trying to run sidekiq on debug mode or even run directly with RubyMine. I can run on console without any error. I tried everything suggested but couldn't fix it.

Error:

```
/bin/zsh -c "bash -c 'env RBENV_VERSION=3.0.5 /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv exec ruby /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-3.0.0.beta.6.1/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --step-over-in-blocks --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 60955 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 60956 -- /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/sidekiq bundle exec -C config/sidekiq_generic.yml'"
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 3.0.0.beta.6.1, debase 3.0.0.beta.6, file filtering is supported, block breakpoints supported, smart steps supported, obtaining return values supported, partial obtaining of instance variables supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:60955
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      Available/installed versions of this gem:
      - 5.18.1
      - 5.16.3
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      Available/installed versions of this gem:
      - 2.1.0
      - 2.0.2
      - 0.6.3
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9, >= 1.6)
      Available/installed versions of this gem:
      - 1.15.2
      - 1.14.3
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Try 'gem cleanup <gem>'
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Uncaught exception: You have already activated tzinfo 2.0.6, but your Gemfile requires tzinfo 1.2.11. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:304:in `check_for_activated_spec!'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:25:in `block in setup'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:165:in `each'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:165:in `each'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `map'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `setup'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:159:in `with_level'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:111:in `silence'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.4.14/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    <internal:/Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
    <internal:/Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:96:in `require'
    /Users/pisano/Pisano/voice/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/pisano/Pisano/voice/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    /Users/pisano/Pisano/voice/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/pisano/Pisano/voice/config/environment.rb:3:in `require_relative'
    /Users/pisano/Pisano/voice/config/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    <internal:/Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
    <internal:/Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:148:in `require'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-6.5.9/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:286:in `boot_application'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-6.5.9/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:53:in `run'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/sidekiq-6.5.9/bin/sidekiq:31:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/sidekiq:25:in `load'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/bin/sidekiq:25:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.6/lib/debase.rb:213:in `load_protect'
    /Users/pisano/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.6/lib/debase.rb:213:in `debug_load'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[Screenshot for my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bGGc.png)

Comment: Just to be sure, what is one the Bundler tab of the Run configuration and how does it go if you run the same configuration in run mode (not debug)?

Comment: I got the same error when I try to run sidekiq(not debug). In my bundler tab bundle exec disabled but even I select auto detection it doesn't work. In bundler tab my Before launch is empty.

Comment: Could you check if the conditions mentioned here for bundler auto detection are met: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2023.3/run-debug-configuration-ruby.html#bundlerTab